# javascript function reports issue missing semicolon, what is the error?

Tags: javascript

I have a very simple function, yet it gives the statement "missing semicolon".

The code is as follows:

```
window.onload = function () {
    var title = document.getElementsByTagName("title")[0].innerHTML;
    document.getElementsByTagName("H1")[0].innerText = title;
}
```

What am i missing here?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you have missing the semicolon at end

```
window.onload = function () {
    var title = document.getElementsByTagName("title")[0].innerHTML;
    document.getElementsByTagName("H1")[0].innerText = title;
};
```

Comment: Ah I am not so familiar with javascript but a function has to end with a semicolon apparently. thanks!